# Plotting a complex function in R

Tags: r, function, statistics

I'm self learning R using a book called "Discovering Statistics using R" and I'm playing around with making graphs as there's quite a lot to learn regarding programming the aesthetics.

The book doesn't really say more than this and I can't find an example on google of a function like the one below. So I'm wondering how to plot this function which is a bit more complex. The example I've got is this:

[image: g(x)]

I've looked through a few plotting questions on here but they don't cover a function like this.

I know how to create a simple plot and a legend etc, but how can this function be plotted in R?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: That is not `complex.`  It's "complicated" .  Complex functions involve $ z = x + iy $

Comment: I guess it's personal preference. Complexity doesn't suggest difficulty, but shows it has many components to handle; in this case, multiple variables/numbers within a function. Ref: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/10459/what-is-the-difference-between-complicated-and-complex

Comment: I would be leery of using **english**.stackexchange as a reference for a mathematical term.  Equations and data are math, not literature, and there is no "preference" here.  Edit: your referenced page has an answer which specifically points out that, in mathematics, this is the only meaning for "complex."

Comment: Feel free to edit the question's title if you think it is more accurate terminology.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
# create a function
myfun <- function(x) 
  ifelse((0 <= x & x <= pi) | ((-2 * pi) <= x & x <= -pi), sin(x), -pi / 4)

# plot a curve
curve(myfun, from = -10, to = 10)
```

[image]

Comment: Oh cool, I like the use of the ifelse function. What would you do in a similar case if there wasn't a 'No' (-Pi/4) part of the function? Is there an alternative to using an ifelse? Thanks for posting.

Comment: @Reanimation In this case I would simply use `sin(x)` instead of the whole `ifelse(...)`.